# date Convert wont give the desired result

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to convert the date in SQL to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM or DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM
I tried everything but the month and day keeps switching
I have changed the number 120 to 105 etc. but the date is converted to MM-DD-YYYY

this is the line of code :

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), hu.CreationDate, 120) + ' ' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hh, hu.CreationDate)), 2) + ':00'
```

this is the whole block of code :

```
SELECT 
  loc.ShortName as Line, art.ERPCode, art.ShortName as Article
  ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), hu.CreationDate, 120) + ' ' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hh, hu.CreationDate)), 2) + ':00' AS ProdHours
  ,Count(hu.Inventory) AS [Pallets]
  ,sum(iif(substring(hu.shortname,2,1) = 0 and substring(hu.shortname,5,1) <> 9,0,1)) as GhostLabels
  ,cast(Sum(hu.Inventory) as decimal(12,0)) AS [Packs]
  ,cast(Sum(hu.Inventory*art.SubItems) as decimal(12,0)) AS [Units]
  ,cast(Sum(hu.Inventory*art.Volume/100) as decimal(12,2)) AS [HL]
FROM 
  RM.TblDatBatch bat
  INNER JOIN RM.TblLstART art on bat.ARTID = art.ARTID
  INNER JOIN EM.TblLstLocation loc on bat.LocationID = loc.LocationID 
  INNER JOIN RM.TblDatLot lot on bat.BatchID = lot.BatchID
  INNER JOIN RM.TblDatHU hu on lot.LotID = hu.LotID-- and (substring(hu.shortname,2,1) = 0 and substring(hu.shortname,5,1) <> 9)
  WHERE loc.ShortName = 'LB6' 
  AND hu.CreationDate > '2021'
GROUP BY loc.ShortName, art.ERPCode, art.ShortName
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), hu.CreationDate, 120) + ' ' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hh, hu.CreationDate)), 2) + ':00'
ORDER BY Line, ProdHours
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  This code is definitely not standard SQL.

Comment: It's far easier to format dates into strings in the UI or report tool.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion style `120` is the nice, standard `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  You want a less scrutable format, so use the appropriate one:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), hu.CreationDate, 103) + ' ' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hh, hu.CreationDate)), 2) + ':00'
```

The available styles are described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can also simplify the time component:

```
(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), hu.CreationDate, 103) + ' ' + 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(TIME(0), hu.CreationDate))
)
```

Comment: I know that YYYY-MM-DD is the way to Go but the user of the report wants the DD/MM/YYYY format.

Comment: @user14182997 in that case modify the **report** to format the date field any way you want. All report tools allow localized formatting and even specifying custom formats for different fields